# Instantiate Interface without Implementation Class

Tags: java

I have an Interface (call it Planet) whose implementation class is protected, and I can not change access modifier for the same. However, I need to call the methods of the implementation class inside of my main class. For example, in the implementation class, I have: `public void orbit() {distance++;}` 
I have tried: `private Planet planet = new PlanetImpl`, but since the PlanetImpl class is protected and in a different package, it can't find it, making the statement invalid. I have also tried leaving it null, like this 
`Planet planet; planet.orbit();`
but it throws a NullPointerException. Is it possible to call the methods without directly referencing the implementation class?

Comment: Could you share the code as well?

Comment: why is the *PlanetImpl class is private*?

Comment: is the `orbit` method part of the interface? How do you usually instantiate these objects?

Comment: Typically you would have a static method which returns an instance or you need to call the constructor. Otherwise you can create an instance.

Comment: Well, if your _PlanetImpl_ class is _private_ then you can't implement any **interface** in Java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using anonymous  inner class we can do it. Anonymous classes can implement interfaces, and i think at that time only you'll have a chance to see a class implementing an interface without the "implements" keyword.

```
interface Planet  {
public void orbit();
}
class PlanetMain  {
private Planet p = new Planet () {
    public void orbit() {
        System.out.println("interface Planet class executed");
   }
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to create an object of that `PlanetImpl` class somewhere to execute the method. The interface has only the definition of that method, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that private/protected impl class is inner class. To call the orbit() method which is a instance method(not static), You need to create a public static factory method in the outer class and call the orbit using the instance provided by this method.

basic code example

```
    public class PlanetImplholder{
    public static Planet getInstance(){
        return new PlanetImpl();
    }

     private static class PlanetImpl  implements Planet{

        @Override
        public void orbit() {
            System.out.println("111");
        }
    }
}
```

call the method from anywhere like below.

```
Planet planet = PlanetImplholder.getInstance();

    planet.orbit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to call the methods without directly referencing the implementation class?

**NO, THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE**. `Interface and implementation class` are just declaration. To use it, you have to create class or interface instance with `new`. But you cannot do it, because you want to use logic of `PlanetImpl`, which is protected.

I think, that you do not want to implement your own class declaration and then create and use new instance of it. I think, that only one way is using reflection. Using it, you can create an instance of protected class `PlanetImpl` and then use it in normal ways.

```
Class<Planet> cls = (Class<Planet>)Class.forName("<full PlanetImpl class name, inclusing package>");
Constructor<Planet> constructor = cls.getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Planet planet = constructor.newInstance();
planet.orbit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but you can use reflection to access the class properties of an object.

```java
Planet planetImpl = factory.getPlanet(); // getPlanet() returns PlanetImpl
Method orbit = planetImpl.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("orbit");
orbit.setAccessible(true);
orbit.invoke(planetImpl);
```

This may not work if a `SecurityManager` prevents access to PlanetImpl.